# object.__init__() takes no arguements

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, kivy, kivy-language

So I'm currently making an app that has a login feature along with the main window that has a menu function within it. I have ran into a problem with the code as I get the error:

`File "C:\Users\Muna Abdullahi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 350, in __init__
     super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 243, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes no arguments`

This is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from database import DataBase
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.config import Config

Window.clearcolor = (0.5294, 0, 0.3176, 0)

Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemandmulti')

class ForgotWindow(Screen):
    namee = ObjectProperty(None)
    email = ObjectProperty(None)

   def VerificationBtn(self):
       pass

   def loginBtn(self):
       sm.current = "login"

class CreateAccountWindow(Screen):
    namee = ObjectProperty(None)
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def submit(self):
        if self.namee.text != "" and self.email.text != "" and self.email.text.count("@") == 1 and self.email.text.count(".") > 0:
            if self.password != "":
                db.add_user(self.email.text, self.password.text, self.namee.text)

                self.reset()

                sm.current = "login"
           else:
               invalidForm()
       else:
           invalidForm()

   def login(self):
       self.reset()
       sm.current = "login"

   def reset(self):
       self.email.text = ""
       self.password.text = ""
       self.namee.text = ""

   def createBtn(self):
       self.reset()
       sm.current = "create"


class LoginWindow(Screen):
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def loginBtn(self):
        if db.validate(self.email.text, self.password.text):
            MainWindow.current = self.email.text
            self.reset()
            sm.current = "main"
        else:
            invalidLogin()

    def createBtn(self):
        self.reset()
        sm.current = "create"

    def forgot(self):
        self.reset()
        sm.current = "forgot"

    def reset(self):
        self.email.text = ""
        self.password.text = ""


class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Screen_One(Screen):
    pass

class Screen_Two(Screen):
    pass



class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


def invalidLogin():
    popup = Popup(title='Invalid Login',
                  content=Label(text='Invalid username or password.'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    popup.open()


def invalidForm():
    popup = Popup(title='Invalid Form',
                  content=Label(text='Please fill in all inputs with valid information.'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))

    popup.open()


kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

sm = WindowManager()
db = DataBase("users.txt")

screens = [LoginWindow(name="login"), 
CreateAccountWindow(name="create"),ForgotWindow(name="forgot"), 
MainWindow(name="main"), Screen_One(name="Screen_One"), 
Screen_Two(name="Screen_Two")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "login"


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run() `
```

If you need my kivy file as well I can send that over.

Can someone please help me with this? I need the code to be fixed soon as it's apart of my school project. Also, if anyone can help me with Kivy, in general, that would be great thanks.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example! https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: From the error text it is pretty clear that `__init__ ` does not expect the argument. Have you tried to debug your own code before posting here? Can you at least comment on the line of the code which is causing the issue?

Comment: It's probably because you are passing `name` keyword arguments, but no such argument name exists. The error you see is what you expect from python in that circumstance.

Comment: Please isolate the part of your code that's causing problems rather than just pasting the entire module

Comment: The error message doesn't list any of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your `MainWindow` class extends `BoxLayout`, but the `BoxLayout` does not support a `name` attribute. You just need to remove the `name` argument from the `MainWindow` creation:

```
MainWindow(name="main")
```

should just be:

```
MainWindow()
```